# Getting user information based on token provided by WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I get user information based on the token provided by WSO2 Identity Server?

I would like to print a custom welcome message to the user, but I have nothing except by access token.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw there is an implementation of OpenId Connect in WSO2 Identity Server that allows to get user info from an OAuth access token, but it's only in the 4.1.1 version (not yet released, i hope it will be released soon).
More  info here : http://sureshatt.blogspot.fr/2013/03/openid-connect-basic-client-profile.html

You can also use the OAuth2TokenValidationService : when you call the validate function on a token, the user name associated to that token is sent in the answer (see OAuth2TokenValidationService.wsdl for more information on this service : https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub/4.0.3/src/main/resources/OAuth2TokenValidationService.wsdl)

The OAuth2TokenValidationService is available in the 4.1.0 version of WSO2 Identity Server